# Matching normal text font with font in math mode in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

So, I tried plotting a logarithm graph and I have a problem where the font of the axis tick label does not match the font of the axis labels. It works fine if the axis labels are written in math mode, then the font style matches. But, I want the font style to match in normal text mode too. This is a sample code.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mpl.use("pgf")
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
mpl.rcParams['mathtext.default'] = "regular"  
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Serif'

a=np.linspace(0,100,101)
b=a**2

plt.plot(a,b)
plt.yscale("log")
plt.ylabel( '$2$   2')
plt.xlabel('$1$    1')

plt.savefig("test.pdf")
```

[image: The image looks like this. So the first number was typed using math mode and it matches with the font of the axis tick labels. The other one was normal and it looks slightly different.]

I tried different combinations but somehow I'm not able to match these two fonts.

Comment: Are you wanting to use a `pgf` file or do you want a `pdf` file? It's not clear as you are using the pgf backend but creating a pdf. If you just want a pdf then you can use a different (default) backend and your code should work (but I think `font.family` should be `serif`).

Comment: The Pdf was just to see how the output looks like. As I said, this is just a sample code to see if I am missing something. I will be using the pgf file as well.

Comment: Thats not how the pgf backend works.  You need to save a pgf file and compile in a LaTeX document.  If you save as pdf, it just re-renders everything, completely ignoring the pgf backend.

Comment: In that case, how can I render in a way that the fonts match in a pdf file?